# Apache James 2.3.2 shuts down after working a few hours

Tags: apache, resources, smtp, james

i've got a strange error on my Apache James 2.3.2 installation.

i Used the James Source Code to change the behaviour of the E-Mail Server to a pass through E-Mail Proxy.
Everything works pretty well for a few hours. After that the James sortof shuts down for no obvious reason.

First i get some Errors in the phoenix.log:

```
INFO    2012-01-30 18:49:55.215 [Phoenix.] (): Unknown resource. Bundle: 'org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.monitor.Resources' Key: 'scanner.skipping-file.notice' Args: '/phoenix/apps/smtp-proxy' Reason: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key scanner.skipping-file.notice

INFO    2012-01-30 18:49:55.232 [Phoenix.] (): Unknown resource. Bundle: 'org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.monitor.Resources' Key: 'scanner.undeploy.notice' Args: 'smtp-proxy' Reason: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key scanner.undeploy.notice

INFO    2012-01-30 18:49:55.233 [Phoenix.] (): 20 Blocks to process for phase "shutdown". Order of processing = [spoolmanager, matcherpackages, mailetpackages, remotemanager, pop3server, smtpserver, fetchmail, James, dnsserver, nntpserver, nntp-repository, spoolrepository, localusersrepository, users-store, mailstore, connections, sockets, scheduler, database-connections, thread-manager].

**INFO    2012-01-30 18:49:55.562 [Phoenix ] (): Shutting down because there are not any applications running.**

ERROR   2012-01-30 18:50:00.350 [Phoenix.] (): Component named "thread-manager" failed to pass through the Destruction stage. (Reason: java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException).

ERROR   2012-01-30 18:50:00.350 [Phoenix.] (): Component named "thread-manager" failed to pass through the Destruction stage. (Reason: java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException).

ERROR   2012-01-30 18:50:00.350 [Phoenix.] (): There was an error running phase "shutdown" for Block named "thread-manager". (Reason: Component named "thread-manager" failed to pass through the Destruction stage. (Reason: java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException).).
```

**Shortly aufter that errors the smtp-server.log shows 2 Exceptions:**

```
30/01/12 18:42:57 ERROR smtpserver: Exception opening socket: Unable to access thread pool due to java.lang.InterruptedException
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access thread pool due to java.lang.InterruptedException
    at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.thread.impl.BasicThreadPool.getWorker(BasicThreadPool.java:164)
    at org.apache.excalibur.thread.impl.AbstractThreadPool.execute(AbstractThreadPool.java:131)
    at org.apache.excalibur.thread.impl.AbstractThreadPool.execute(AbstractThreadPool.java:120)
    at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.thread.impl.DefaultThreadPool.execute(DefaultThreadPool.java:115)
    at org.apache.james.util.watchdog.InaccurateTimeoutWatchdog.start(InaccurateTimeoutWatchdog.java:106)
    at proxy.james.smtpserver.SMTPHandler.handleConnection(SMTPHandler.java:374)
    at org.apache.james.util.connection.ServerConnection$ClientConnectionRunner.run(ServerConnection.java:432)
    at org.apache.excalibur.thread.impl.ExecutableRunnable.execute(ExecutableRunnable.java:55)
    at org.apache.excalibur.thread.impl.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:116)
30/01/12 18:42:57 ERROR smtpserver: Exception opening socket: Unable to access thread pool due to java.lang.InterruptedException
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access thread pool due to java.lang.InterruptedException
    at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.thread.impl.BasicThreadPool.getWorker(BasicThreadPool.java:164)
    at org.apache.excalibur.thread.impl.AbstractThreadPool.execute(AbstractThreadPool.java:131)
    at org.apache.excalibur.thread.impl.AbstractThreadPool.execute(AbstractThreadPool.java:120)
    at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.thread.impl.DefaultThreadPool.execute(DefaultThreadPool.java:115)
    at org.apache.james.util.watchdog.InaccurateTimeoutWatchdog.start(InaccurateTimeoutWatchdog.java:106)
    at proxy.james.smtpserver.SMTPHandler.handleConnection(SMTPHandler.java:374)
    at org.apache.james.util.connection.ServerConnection$ClientConnectionRunner.run(ServerConnection.java:432)
    at org.apache.excalibur.thread.impl.ExecutableRunnable.execute(ExecutableRunnable.java:55)
    at org.apache.excalibur.thread.impl.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:116)
```

**I guess that the Exceptions in the smtp-server.log are some kind of followup Exceptions because of the shutting down of the phoenix container.**

Did anyone see this behaviour, because i really cant explain why for hours everything is working fine and suddenly the phoenix shuts down...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ups, the stacktrace has the Timestamp 18:49:56 not 18:42:57 - copyed the wrong log

Comment: err, just edit the question so that the log is correct.  run again, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the people suffering from the same issue:
The problem was that the hotdeployment was activated in the phoenix container.

Everytime a monitoring service touched the sar-archive of the aplpication it has been redeployed. - Unfortunateley the server doesn't like it ad all!

After deactivating the hot deploy everything works fine now!